# Why should we couple AGND and DGND?

Tags: grounding, signal-processing

[image]

we can see the connection at the right hand side between the DGND and AGND! according to my course text,**"the real electronic ground of the system is where the point AGND and DGND are coupled."** but it doesn't explain clearly why? Why do we need to couple them together?

Comment: ... Because both parts still need a common reference.

Answer (score 1):

The 'ground' is the reference voltage for a signal.  For instance, on the left, you have an ADC block.  The ADC reads the voltage into that block **with reference to AGND** and saves that voltage into some registers.

Once the digital side of that block decides to interface, then the digital signals are read **with reference to the DGND**.

Unfortunately, unless the IC or circuit is specifically designed for isolation, the DGND and AGND of most parts cannot be significantly different or bad things will happen on the silicon.  We try to separate AGND and DGND from a layout (and often schematic) standpoint to reduce the interference between the two circuit references.  There are books written about how to do this well.

Answer (score 0):

AGND and DGND are still GND. They form your common (and likely, necessary) reference for the entire circuit. The reason they are only connected in one place is to eliminate any loop currents from different circuits interfering with each other, i.e., the ground current for the "Logic" block in your diagram will not flow through any of the AGND nodes, but through the DGND nodes back to the supply. Since none of this current flows in the AGND nodes, you won't induce any voltage change in the AGND nodes (your analog circuits are conceivably sensitive to small changes in their GND voltage), which allows your analog circuits to have a cleaner, more stable GND voltage.